# How to use filter on link entity?

Tags: c#, filter, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, query-expressions

I'm using crm 2016 and trying to get a product (custom entity) records according to linkentity filtering, I need to get all products that have Active productstatus and the **linked** phonecall category is `fun` and `not open`:

> PRODUCT - (productstatus = Active) & (linkedphonecallcategory = fun &&
>   linkedphonecallstatus != open)

When I run my current query, the results I get are without the linked entity filter. I don't understand why.

This is my code:

```cs
FilterExpression filter1 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("phonecallcategory", ConditionOperator.Equal, "fun"));
filter1.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("statecode", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, 0));

LinkEntity phoneCallLink = new LinkEntity("product", "phonecall", "productid", "regardingobjectid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
phoneCallLink.LinkCriteria = filter1;
phoneCallLink.EntityAlias = "products";

QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("product");
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("productname");
query.LinkEntities.Add(phoneCallLink);
query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("productstatus", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0)); 

EntityCollection AllProductsWithSpecificCallsNotOpen = new EntityCollection();
```

Comment: Can you write in SQL what you are trying to get?

Comment: Can you show the code where you execute this query?

Comment: As a side-note, this shouldn't be a `left-outer` join.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here `QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("product");`

Your question says that your `Product` is a custom entity, but you've used the schema name of the system entity `Product` which does not allow Activities.

You have to use the logical (all lowercase) name of your entity

You can also generate this code using the **XrmToolbox**. Here's a sample query I generated using this tool. Please note:

- I've used `Contact` instead of `Product`
- I've removed the join type so it reverts to an inner join

Code:

```
// Initialise
var QEcontact = new QueryExpression("contact");

// Add columns to QEcontact.ColumnSet
QEcontact.ColumnSet.AddColumns("firstname");

// Add link-entity QEcontact_phonecall
var QEcontact_phonecall = QEcontact.AddLink("phonecall", "contactid", "regardingobjectid");

// Define filter QEcontact_phonecall.LinkCriteria
QEcontact_phonecall.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("category", ConditionOperator.Equal, "fun");
QEcontact_phonecall.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("statuscode", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share this readable format of your expected query. Also like other answer mentioned, use Advanced find or fetchXML builder in XrmToolBox to build fetchxml query, you can view SQL and query expression equivalent there itself.

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("product")
{
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("productname"), 
    Criteria = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And)
    {
        Conditions =
        {
               new ConditionExpression("productstatus", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0)
        }
    },
    LinkEntities =
    {
        new LinkEntity("product", "phonecall", "productid", "regardingobjectid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter)
        {
            Columns = new ColumnSet("phonecallcategory"),
            LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And)
            {
                Conditions =
                {
                    new ConditionExpression("statecode", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, 0),
                    new ConditionExpression("phonecallcategory", ConditionOperator.Equal, "fun")
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a FetchXml query instead. With this method you make your filter using Advanced Find. Then, in the window you download the FetchXml. It's by far easier to debug.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328332.aspx

Answer (score 0):

May you can have a look here, i have restructured your query to make it easy to understand

**Example: QueryExpression with LinkEntity**

```cs
//Link
LinkEntity phoneCallLink = new LinkEntity();
phoneCallLink.LinkFromEntityName  = "new_product";
phoneCallLink.LinkToEntityName = "phonecall";
phoneCallLink.LinkFromAttributeName = "new_productid";
phoneCallLink.LinkToAttributeName = "regardingobjectid";
phoneCallLink.JoinOperator = JoinOperator.LeftOuter;
phoneCallLink.EntityAlias = "phone";
phoneCallLink.LinkCriteria.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("statecode", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, 0));
phoneCallLink.LinkCriteria.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("phonecallcategory", ConditionOperator.Equal, "fun"));

//Query
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("new_product");
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_name");
query.LinkEntities.Add(phoneCallLink);
query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0)); 

//Execute
var AllProductsWithSpecificCallsNotOpen = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

In case this is still not working you can build & export a `fetchXml` query and convert it to Query Expression as:

**Example: Convert FetchXml to QueryExprssion**

```cs
    string fetchXml =
    @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
  <entity name='account'>
    <attribute name='name' />
    <attribute name='accountid' />
    <order attribute='createdon' descending='true' />
    <order attribute='modifiedon' descending='true' />
    <filter type='and'>
      <condition attribute='createdon' operator='this-month' />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>";
    
    // Convert the FetchXML into a query expression.
    var conversionRequest = new FetchXmlToQueryExpressionRequest();
    conversionRequest.FetchXml = fetchXml; //fetchXml string

    var conversionResponse =(FetchXmlToQueryExpressionResponse)service.Execute(conversionRequest);
    var result = conversionResponse.Results.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
LinkEntity phoneCallLink = new LinkEntity("product", "phonecall", "productid", "regardingobjectid", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
```

To:

```
LinkEntity phoneCallLink = new LinkEntity("product", "phonecall", "productid", "regardingobjectid", JoinOperator.Inner);
```